# IntelliJ - Gradle: How to get rid of the test source folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Yes, indeed this is a noob question. Alas, I am one when it comes to Gradle...

Everything is going okay, just that an annoying test folder is created when I don't need one.
The test folder's path is "src/test". Don't even know why it's there.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    version = '1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        mavenCentral()
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.fxmisc.richtext', name: 'richtextfx', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle follows the convention that tests live under `src/test` and will automatically run tests there when certain tasks are executed like `gradle check`.

Did you happen to check the "Create directories for empty content roots automatically" when creating/importing the project in IntelliJ? That might be the culprit.

Deleting that folder shouldn't have any adverse affect.